# How can I upgrade latexmk / why very old version is contained in Ubuntu repository?

Tags: apt, upgrade, package-management, latex

Each time when I build my [R markdown](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_quick_tour.html) (Knit the current) document to have LaTeX and PDF files, I see in RStudio a warning message:

> Your latexmk version seems to be too low. You may need to update the
>   latexmk package or your LaTeX distribution.

Page https://www.ctan.org/pkg/latexmk says that current version of latexmk is 4.52c

However when I type

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install --only-upgrade latexmk
```

I see on my screen:

```
latexmk is already the newest version (1:4.41-1).
```

which is consistent with information which I get when I type:

```
latexmk --version
```

> Latexmk, John Collins, 1 January 2015. Version 4.4

I wonder if it is possible to (and if I should) upgrade latexmk on my Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS or should I just ignore this warning?
Is there any different PPA for latexmk / RStudio dependencies?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I am extensively using the provided `latexmk` in my 16.04 system without any problem --- but I do not use `R`, so your case may be different.

The new version has new capabilities (like direct selection of `lualatex` and `xelatex` engines), so the reason for not upgrading it may be one (or both) of:

- that the package's maintainer thinks it's too risky for a LTS release (but then it should be available a version for the update in newer Ubuntu, and i[t seems it is not the case](http://packages.ubuntu.com/yakkety/latexmk))
- Or simply the upgrades were not noticed by the maintainer, or they're too busy, or not interested anymore.

If you look at the files contents of the `latexmk` package, you'll find that practically it's just a script and documentation:

```
[romano:~] % wajig listfiles latexmk
/.
/usr
/usr/bin
/usr/bin/latexmk
/usr/share
/usr/share/man
/usr/share/man/man1
/usr/share/man/man1/latexmk.1L.gz
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/latexmk
/usr/share/doc/latexmk/latexmk.txt.gz
/usr/share/doc/latexmk/latexmk.ps.gz
/usr/share/doc/latexmk/copyright
/usr/share/doc/latexmk/latexmk.pdf.gz
/usr/share/doc/latexmk/README.gz
/usr/share/doc/latexmk/changelog.Debian.gz
/etc
/etc/LatexMk
```

(and the global configuration file).

So in case of a need of an upgrade, I would probably [download the source package from  its home](http://personal.psu.edu/jcc8//software/latexmk-jcc/), and then install locally in my user. The installiation instructions are really well done, but basically it boils down to

```
cp latexmk.pl $HOME/bin/latexmk 
chmod +x $HOME/bin/latexmk
```

and now the new `latexmk` is overriding the old one. If you want to install it system-wide, the instructions are, again, quite complete.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer! However, I think it's rather a workaround for someone who needs to install latest version. I wish to know what was the reason to not include latest latexmk in the repo (maybe it is not stable / have bugs?)

Comment: Answer updated.